# Get action types from Redux Toolkit's createSlice

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I'm using `createSlice` together with `useReducer`.

I'd like the dispatch to be typed properly, that is `React.Dispatch<ReducerActions>`.

### How do I extract action types from `createSlice`?

The following does not work, it resolves to `AnyAction`... which is understandable I'd say, as all actions pass through all reducers.

```
Dispatch<Parameters<typeof slice["reducer"]>[1]>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`createSlice` stores the action creators as a keyed object in the property `actions`.  What we are looking for is the union of the return types of all action creators.  We will use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) to get this.

```
type SliceActions<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => infer A ? A : never;
}[keyof T]

type ActionTypes = SliceActions<typeof slice.actions>
```

I used the counter example from the doc in this [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHakDCGAzmgEpo6AVyJQmLdj1IAhXmgms2ndFmhwAvnABmUCCDgByAALoRADwBWPAPQwIEPAGtgMQwFgAUF%20BtsUbQwiOE4IYT80KBwYLDRELzg4ADcMPGE0AC44NmEQACNIrw0vL2QpeF9XYFTo2KzQ8P9a7DgAXkRk1PSsgAZNEs8yth54MsbI-EI49tRMbEmiAAoEBOyMEEyjMYioQ2JVypYamOx9z0SzUUieLJXzxLhfWY2-RZHYgEp4%204e4d%20wAHQpNJoADUoNWiQ0Z1%20dDQzzQr3%20aC%20d1%20iWRQK6aAAtDjIZoYQ8nugXjAZJQGCAwkiTiQ4EFJGwshRqLRGMwlAAeHL5SIAPlRBIxdKxILgoPajKUALAVBo9AJ0NWys8Gg%20AxglDAcQWCk5Ui5ABV%20W1vr8ANoAaUebDgTjQlAg2jgRoAulkjda3XA0OZsGw6Dw4IsAWGMFAAOY3BlsSgWt1fVqm3zaSJwBhwAD8GbgWTYaCSkQA3EULQ6nS73ZrtXFFOwjbXg%2009fXhlytTrnSgaU0CEQAdKpPyBn7ILAe8N4EgSWgyaQ4Qi-KRZ2SKVTe5ozds%201NBwbhl4x9B4HDAsI8KNexN%202gAZcxEA) and the value of `ActionTypes` evaluated to:

```
type ActionTypes = {
    payload: undefined;
    type: "counter/increment";
} | {
    payload: undefined;
    type: "counter/decrement";
} | {
    payload: number;
    type: "counter/incrementByAmount";
}
```

When I first wrote this answer (October 2020) the action types were inferred as `type: string` rather than specific string literals.  With the latest versions of Redux Toolkit and TypeScript (as of March 2023) you actually get the exact types!

Comment: They should include `SliceActions` type into redux toolkit itself. Do a PR maybe?

Comment: @jayarjo It is a conscious decision not to use union types in redux toolkit.  Instead everything is based upon type guard functions rather than descriminated unions.  For example, if `setUser.match(action)` is `true` then you know that your payload is a `User`.  @phry who is one of the RTK maintainers wrote an article about this: https://phryneas.de/redux-typescript-no-discriminating-union

Answer (score 3):

Based on Linda type, There is another way for better typing:

```
const storeSlice = createSlice({
  //...
  reducers: {
    fetchData: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      //...
    onFetchFailed: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
      //...
    },
  },
});
type SliceActions<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {type: K; payload: T[K] extends (...args: infer P) => void ? P[0] : never};
}[keyof T];

/* 
ActionTypes = {
    type: "fetchData";
    payload: string;
} | {
    type: "onFetchFailed";
    payload: string;
}
*/
type ActionTypes = SliceActions<typeof storeSlice.actions>;
```

Comment: Swapping out this code lost the prefix of the slice, the other answer seems to give literals eg `name/action`